# Expressão regular que aceite somente números e/ou letras em Java

Tags: java, regex

Como desenvolver uma expressão regular que permita que uma string tenha somente números **e/ou** letras em qualquer posição e quantidades?

Exemplos:

> a) **000000000a**
>
> b) **000000000A**
>
> c) **AAAAAAAAA0**
>
> d) **1AAAAA1113**
>
> e) **1111111111111111111111111a**
>
> f) **aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa4**
>
> g) **1234567678909090**

**EDITADO**

A expressão deve ter obrigatoriamente números e opcionalmente letras sem acentuação gráfica (cedilha não entra, por exemplo). O meu objetivo é criar um método para avaliar se uma string dada casou com o padrão, ou seja, o retorno será true ou false.

Comment: Qual é o comportamento esperado: Você quer que o regex retorne true/false; ou você quer retirar os caracteres indesejáveis da String?

Comment: Só precisa retornar true ou false, @Math

Comment: @Math, se você puder fazer uma releitura da questão e adaptar à sua  resposta, agradeço. Acabei por esquecer um detalhe importante: preciso de uma string com número e/ou letras (sem acento).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exigindo pelo menos um inteiro:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9]*\d+[A-Za-z0-9]*$"); // ou ^[^\W_]*\d+[^\W_]*$ seguindo a ideia do mgibsonbr
return p.matcher(textoDeTeste).matches();
```

Pode testar ela no http://www.regexr.com/, mas lembre-se de marcar a flag multline lá no canto superior direito se quiser testar testar com várias linhas diferentes ao mesmo tempo (cada linha sendo uma entrada).

Link do Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/ufBplCyRLv

Comment: Pedro, se você puder fazer uma releitura da questão e adaptar a sua  resposta, agradeço. Acabei por esquecer um detalhe importante: preciso de uma string com número e/ou letras (sem acento).

Comment: @GeisonSantos, alterado de acordo com a modificação da pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Normalmente o padrão `\w` (*word*, palavra) casa qualquer letra, número e underscore (`_`). Dessa forma, `\w*` casaria uma string com qualquer número de caracteres desse tipo (incluindo a string vazia), e `\w+` a mesma coisa, só que exigiria pelo menos um caractere.

Essa seria a solução mais completa, pois definir letras em um intervalo (ex.: `[a-zA-Z]`) apenas consideraria caracteres ASCII, sem aceitar por exemplo letras acentuadas (`á`). Para fazer com que Java aceite casar `\w` com letras Unicode, basta prefixar o padrão com `(?U)` [[fonte]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4307261/520779). Se você não se interessa por Unicode (i.e. só quer letras ASCII mesmo), basta omitir esse prefixo (ou usar as soluções alternativas dadas nas demais respostas - que também estariam corretas nesse caso).

Se a presença do underscore é um problema, podemos eliminá-lo através de uma "negação dupla":

```
[^\W_]
```

Ou seja: "case tudo o que não é uma 'não palavra' nem um underscore". [Exemplo no rubular](http://rubular.com/r/kHyJZGbFGw). (Nota: caso não tenha ficado claro, `\w` - em minúsculas - casa a classe de caracteres "palavra"; `\W` - em maiúsculas - inverte, casando tudo o que não é dessa classe de caracteres; `[...]` casa um dentre um conjunto de caracteres; `[^...]` inverte, casando tudo o que não é um desses caracteres)

Para utilizá-la, o método mais simples é através de [`String.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) (verifica se a string inteira casa com a expressão passada como parâmetro), ou se usando `Pattern` e `Matcher` para outros comportamentos:

```
"abc".matches("(?U)[^\W_]*"); // true

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?U)[^\W_]*");

p.matcher("abc").matches();   // ok, a string inteira casa com o padrão
p.matcher("$a$").find();      // ok, o padrão pode ser achado na string
p.matcher("ab$").lookingAt(); // ok, a string começa com o padrão
```

Comment: mgibsonbr, se você puder fazer uma releitura da questão e adaptar a sua  resposta, agradeço. Acabei por esquecer um detalhe importante: preciso de uma string com número e/ou letras (sem acento).

Comment: @GeisonSantos Não há muito a ser adaptado... Se você quer que Unicode seja levado em consideração, prefixe com `(?U)`, se você não quer, não prefixe. Vou acrescentar uma nota sobre isso, e é bom salientar também que - nesse caso - as demais respostas também estão corretas (escolha aquela que te agrada mais).

Comment: Certo, @mgibsonbr. Ah, muito boa a dica do Rubular.

Comment: Qual seria a diferença entre `[^\W_]` e `[\w_]`?

Comment: @Patrick, a primeira não casa com `_`, a segunda sim.

Comment: @Patrick Além disso, `[\w_]` é redundante, porque `\w` sozinho já aceita `_` (i.e. ambas são equivalentes). `[^...]` nega tudo o que está dentro dos colchetes. Por exemplo, se você quisesse uma regex para casar só letras (sem números), você poderia fazer: `[^\W\d_]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Regex {

    public static boolean validaString(String str) {
        return str.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] teste = {"asdfads89as89", "", "asdf 98s", "asd©áßsas90", 
                          "asdfas78237", "2342", "abc",};
        //tudo o que não for de a->z ou de A->Z ou de 0->9 será removido
        for(String s: teste){
            String resultado = (validaString(s))?"\' é válida" :"\' é inválida";
            System.out.println("A String \'" + s + resultado);
        }
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
A String 'asdfads89as89' é válida
A String '' é inválida
A String 'asdf 98s' é inválida
A String 'asd©áßsas90' é inválida
A String 'asdfas78237' é válida
A String '2342' é válida
A String 'abc' é válida
```

Comment: Kyllopardiun, se você puder fazer uma releitura da questão e adaptar a sua  resposta, agradeço. Acabei por esquecer um detalhe importante: preciso de uma string com número e/ou letras (sem acento).

Comment: @GeisonSantos, adaptada para o formato pedido.