# ion-input somente números delimitada ionic3

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Bom dia pessoal, sou novo no ionic, fiz uma pesquisa pelo site mas não achei uma resposta para a minha dúvida. Vejam se conseguem me ajudar:

Quero delimitar uma entrada de dados somente de números.

O atributo maxlength não funciona no tipo number somente no tipo tel. Porém, no tipo tel é possível inserir letras e caracteres especiais como # e *.

Além disso, no tipo number é possível inserir ponto.

Eu gostaria de somente números, com quantidade de algarismos máxima de 5.
Alguém saberia me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode fazer um Regex para limitar isso.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25605/express%C3%A3o-regular-que-aceite-somente-n%C3%BAmeros-e-ou-letras-em-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui. Eis minha solução:
No arquivo.ts

```
formatar()
    {
       var login = this.login.rg;

       if(this.login.rg != undefined){
        login = login.replace(/\D/g, '');
        this.login.rg = login;
        console.log(this.login.rg);
       }

    }
```

No arquivo .html:

```
<ion-input type="tel"  (keyup)="formatar()" maxlength="5" size="4" clearInput placeholder="Digite seu RG (Somente números)" pattern="[0-9]" [(ngModel)]="login.rg" name="rg"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim no seu ion-input:

```
<ion-input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*"></ion-input>
```

Funciona no:

- iOS 9/10+
- Android 5+

Comment: Não funcionou amigo. Continua aceitando pontos, vírgula, tralha, asterisco etc.

Comment: desculpe, coloquei o type errado, use o "tel"